# Android Asynchronous Http Client & Configuration Changes

Tags: android, asynchronous, configuration

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this scenario.

Let's say I send a GET request to my API.
Before it finishes I rotate the device.
Now I no longer get a response back because my activity has been destroyed and recreated.

What should I do in this scenario?

Here is the library I'm using
https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

Comment: do you insist on using that library? try another one that handle these issues for you!

Comment: @mmlooloo Do you have any suggestions? I'm interested :)

Comment: @mmlooloo This looks like it also can replace universal-image-loader and it's maintained by Google. :D

Comment: yes and also you can use json request and response and make it use Gson and a lot of other enhancements.

Comment: @mmlooloo I'm failing to see how Volley solves the rotation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a headless fragment. If this is not a good idea let me know ;)

Answer (score 1):

i will answer it briefly so you can use the ideas further. 
first thing to use volley is creating `Singleton Request Queue`, at `Google` site it shows you how to do that.

how volley handles your request?

volley puts your request in to the queue.By default it uses 5 threads. Responsibilities of 4 threads are sending your requests to the server and another one is responsible for reading your request from request queue. volley also uses a disk cache.The single thread dequeue your request from request queue and check it by internal cache. if its response is in the cache volley dose not make any internet request and just returning back the result from memory. when new response comes volley checks header file and if it can cache your response(server allows response to be cached) it caches the response and saves it into the disk. All of these story happening in the worker threads. so whats happening when your activity destroys? if the response of your old request arrives volley caches them and again if you ask it to fetch the url volley reads from memory and dose not send any request to the server. if it has already sent your request, again when you ask new request it checks it and find out that your response is on the flight so volley dose not request again. but if you want to request some thing new when your activity destroys just cancel old requests in `onDestroy()` to get new result fast because in this case volley cancel all of the old requests and dose not deliver you any old results. this is how volley does!!

Comment: Okay, so if I'm say fetching a list and rotate the screen. I resend the request and Volley will detect the duplicate request and give me the cached response. What if I'm in the middle of a POST request?

Comment: volley caches all response, you again send your post request and if volley has already saved that just read from memory else wait to get back result.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to play around with it. Once I've done some testing I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: very good, and if you face any issues or finding my answer is incorrect let me know to learn from you.

Comment: So far all the examples show the Activity classes containing the actual URL for the GET/POST requests. Is this really wise? I prefer having a seperate class to contain all the network code, then I use a method like 'loadAllData()'. This way if I need to change the way my code interacts with an API I only have to change it in one class. Any thoughts?

Comment: i think you can use that pattern, at first time i used this library i actually struggled to create such pattern and i succeed to some extent, but actually i think there is no need for example for GET request you can create a class that creates the URL because all you need to change is the URL, and for post you must provide URL and Map. i have not done that but i think you CAN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59825/discussion-between-hackmodford-and-mmlooloo).